# A type or namespace name 'register' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, compiler-errors

I always get this problem when I link forms in C#.
Here's the code of the first form:

```
using ybird;

public partial class form1 : Form
{
    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            register form = new register();
            register.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception w)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(w.Message, Application.ProductName);
        }
    }
 }
```

And here's the code for the Register.cs:

```
namespace ybird
{
    public partial class register : Form
    { 
    }
}
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Please don't dump all of your code here - just what's relevant. Also - why are you telling us this is urgent? We are not paid to solve your problems - they may be urgent for you, but telling us that it is urgent is just plain rude.

Comment: Also, please tell us exactly what you mean when you say 'link forms'. And since it is probably compile-time error, (I bet it has nothing to do with linking,) please tell us precisely at which line of your source file you get that error.

Comment: Telling us what the error you are getting will also help.

Comment: @Oded he told us what the error was in the title. What he forgot to tell us is where the error was. But I see you went ahead and you found it anyway. I admire your patience.

Comment: That's assuming that he knows the difference between "Static" and "Instance"

Comment: Guys...sorry...mistakenly added the word Urgent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will not work, as `Show` is an *instance* method, not a `static` mathod:

```
register form = new register();
register.Show();
```

You probably meant:

```
register form = new register();
form.Show();
```

Note:

Your naming is non standard - types in .NET are normally in PascalCase - to be consistent, your should name the class `Register`. Additionally, using the variable `form` is not very descriptive - `registerForm` would be better.